# Initializing Constants in Class Constructor

Tags: c++

Edit: add .h file.

```
#pragma once
#include "Screen.h"
#include "../IniParams.h"

class AtcParamsMenu : public Screen
{

public:
AtcParamsMenu(ScreenManager *screenMgr, MenuTypes MenuType, IniParams *Params);
~AtcParamsMenu();

private:
enum eFields
{
    make,
    model,
    connector
};

void processKey();
void updateScreen(bool refreshAll);
void selectMaker();
void deSelectMaker();
void setMaker(AtcManufacturer maker);
void setModel();
void setCabinetType();

unsigned char idx;
unsigned char fieldIdx;
const unsigned char addY;// = 1

const unsigned char xIdx;// = 14
const unsigned char dispXidx; // = 15
const unsigned char fieldLen; // = 9
static const eFields minField = make;
static const eFields maxField = connector;

IniParams *params;
MenuTypes menuType;
```

};

Here is a class constructor.

Note the last 4 variables are constant unsigned chars from the .h file. This is not a base class, but I prefer not to use static for these.

Is this considered a 'clean' way to initialize constants?  Some of my classes might end up with 7 or 8 of these.

```
AtcParamsMenu::AtcParamsMenu(ScreenManager *screenMgr, MenuTypes MenuType, IniParams *Params) : 
Screen(screenMgr), addY(1), xIdx(14), dispXidx(15), fieldLen(9)
```

Comment: It is the only way to initialize a const member if you get their value from the "user"

Comment: There's *far* from enough context to give any advise on this code.

Comment: You can initialize them directly in the class body.

Comment: 'I prefer not to use static for these', Why? Static solves your problem.

Comment: I added the .h file code to the question. @HolyBlackCat, please post example of setting the values in the class body. thanks.

Comment: `class A {const int x = 42;};` Though this is not going to work on your compiler, since you say it doesn't support C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't see enough of your code to give a full review of the situation, but here are some notes:

1. This is the correct way, in general, to initialise members
2. For simple initialisers like this, since C++11 you can provide them inline:

   ```
   struct Foo
   {
      ScreenManager* screenMgr;
      const int myConstant = 42;

      Foo(ScreenManager* screenMgr);
   };

   Foo::Foo(ScreenManager* screenMgr)
      : screenMgr(screenMgr)
   {}
   ```
3. However, since the initialisations don't depend on any inputs at all, and don't appear to be instance-specific, they *should* probably be `static const`, despite your reservations
4. If they are `static const`, you do not initialise them in the constructor, but define them separately. Like this:

   ```
   struct Foo
   {
      static const int myConstant;
      ScreenManager* screenMgr;           

      Foo(ScreenManager* screenMgr);
   };

   const int Foo::myConstant = 42;

   Foo::Foo(ScreenManager* screenMgr)
      : screenMgr(screenMgr)
   {}
   ```

Comment: We are using an older compiler, not C++11.  Thanks for the useful info.

Comment: The only issue I have with using static is memory management.  It seems to me that having several static values that might never be used would be a waste of resources. Since the class in question would be dynamically called, I did not want to allocate methods that may not ever be called.

Comment: @netcat: If you have values that are never used, remove them. Otherwise, your way is worse, because you are taking up space for each single constant in each single instance of `AtcParamsMenu`. My way, there is only one each, ever. In fact, if it turns out that the values aren't needed at runtime, your linker can completely remove them from the executable! Space is not something you need to be concerned about here.

Comment: Thanks, I get what you are saying, but there will only be one instance of this class at a time. Also, the user may or may not ever touch this menu, so it might never be called. Since the compiler cannot know, I think it would have to allocate every static variable, since the class can be called any time during the life of the app.

Comment: @netcat: If you really think saving the space of four `unsigned char` in your executable is worth making an unidiomatic and unclear design, that's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

In c++11 you can initialize directly in the class declaration which looks more cleaner :

```
class AtcParamsMenu
{
    const int addY = 1;
    const int xIdx = 14;
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately we are stuck using a toolchain from an older version of g++, so c++11  is not supported.